# Default variable value in blade Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

How do I set a default value to a variable in a blade partial?

So for example I have 2 variables:

- softDelete
- delete

witch I want by default to be true.

```
@if($softDelete)
    <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Publish">
        <a href="#delete-{{ $id }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-flat">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </a>
    </span>
@endif

@if($delete)
    <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">
        <a href="#delete-{{ $id }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete btn-flat details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_modal">
            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
        </a>
    </span>
@endif
```

And when I send the view from controller to change the value for some of the variables, depending the case I need.

```
return view('platform.pages.blocks.property_table_actions',
    [
        'id' => $model->id,
        'delete' => false
    ]);
```

I tried with a provider:

```
public function composeActionButtons()
{
    view()->composer('platform.pages.blocks.property_table_actions', function ($view) {
        $view
            ->with('softDelete', true)
            ->with('delete', true)
            ->with('view', true)
            ->with('edit', true);
    });
}
```

but override the false values from controller.

Comment: You can use blades ternary shortcut `{{ $delete or true }}`

Comment: Undefined variable: delete .

Comment: @IonVasile Then your statement "I have 2 variables" is incorrect, at least in the view's scope.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you may wish to echo a variable, but you aren't sure if the variable has been set. Basically, you want to do this:

{{ isset($name) ? $name : 'Default' }}

However, instead of writing a ternary statement, Blade allows you to use the following convenient short-cut:

{{ $name or 'Default' }}

---

from the laravel docs..
it should check with isset if the variable exists.. if not a default value is shown

Comment: The logic is not good: `@if(isset($edit) or true)
    <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">
    </span>
@endif` will always be true. There must be a way by default to set all variables to true, and when I render a view to set false only the button I need.

Comment: to be clear you want all variables default on true, only if you override it in the controller as false right?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want.

Comment: Then you can solve it via the blade default variable.. or this http://pastebin.com/0xTYHSMt

Comment: With the code in pastebin the default will be `false` for all variables, and I need true.

Comment: maybe your provider ovverides that? .. have you tried to put it in a middleware? like that : http://pastebin.com/5fccjTi3

Comment: Please take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921911/default-variable-value-in-blade-laravel/37951097#37951097

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching this task in the wrong way - personally. But if you insist, you could also just include a partial (I do this sometimes). Say in a variable, etc.

For example, something like this:

```
// in your view
@include('some.directory.for.partials', ['softDelete' => 'false']) // you can change this to any value

// partial can then run something like this:
@if(count($softDelete) || $softDelete)
    ...
@else
    ...
@endif
```

***That said***, I think you could probably just assign the variable in your controller when you're rendering your view. You're assigning a variable anyways. Why make things complicated with a view composer - when that logic could be in your controller? Just set `'delete' => false` to true or what have you for each.

Comment: I would like to know the best practice way. How would you approach? To be clear I want all variables default on true, only if I override it in the controller as false.

Comment: I would define the variable already in the controller before the view is rendered. You're already doing that in your `return view(...` anyways. Define the variable there. Don't make things complicated. :)

Comment: Yes but I have 20 crud controllers, and for each of them I have or not have some of that buttons. And by default I want to have all variables true. In the question I gave 2 buttons as example but in my case I have 5. So if I follow your example I would have to write for each of this buttons if true or false. And my intention was to declare false if only is neede.

Comment: Then just use my example. You don't need the view composer (the problem with a view composer is the variables will be added last and will override your controller ones. So think of this logic backwards and reverse the process). Create a partial for those buttons. They're all visible by default, based on an `@if conditional` in the partial. If one is `FALSE`, enter variable in the `@include` method like in my example.

Comment: Please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921911/default-variable-value-in-blade-laravel/37951097#37951097

Answer (score 0):

I found the best method to be this:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Providers;

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
 use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

 class ViewComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Bootstrap the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->composeActionButtons();
}

/**
 * Register the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Compose the Recent sidebar
 */
public function composeActionButtons()
{
    view()->creator('platform.pages.blocks.property_table_actions', function ($view) {
        $view
            ->with('softDelete', true)
            ->with('delete', true)
            ->with('view', true)
            ->with('edit', true);
    });

}
}
```

and in controller:

```
  return view('platform.pages.blocks.property_table_actions',
    [
        'id' => $model->id,
    ])
    ->with(['edit' =>false, 'softDelete' => false]);
```

View creators work almost exactly like view composers; however, they are fired immediately when the view is instantiated.
The callback that I defined with the Creator is called immediately after view() , which is before any ->with()s.  This enables me to set a default value for the View and then override it when the View is called, if desired.

Comment: Looks good - if it works, it works. :) Not,e you don't need to use `with` twice like that it can accept arrays. So `->with(['edit' =>false, 'softDelete' => false]);`

Comment: Ohh, Good to know. :)

Comment: Checkity check... https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#passing-data-to-views

Answer (score -1):

In Controller.php

```
function __construct() {
    $softDelete= true;
    $data = array('softDelete'  => $softDelete);
    view()->share($data);
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks